# Shell - Creating text file which appends content - Using cat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I have this code for example:

```
rm /etc/rc.local
cat <<EOF >/etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
apt-get update && apt-get -y install git-core
EOF
```

Is there a way instead of having it so I don't need to delete the original rc.local and make a new one, but instead I can use pretty much the same code but **append** this content to the bottom of the rc.local file, rather than recreating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
cat <<EOF >>/etc/rc.local

apt-get update && apt-get -y install git-core
EOF
```

Or simply :

```
echo 'apt-get update && apt-get -y install git-core' >> /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: I shouldn't need this line anymore then right?! rm /etc/rc.local

Comment: @Jimmy you didn't need the `rm` in the first place anyway: `>` completely replaces the content of the file so `rm` was redundant. Actually `>` behaves like `rm` followed by `>>`